# Recorrer varias array obtenidos de manera dinamica con php

Tags: php, array, bucle-for

Obtengo diferentes array que se almacenan en variables de manera dinámica, podría ser algo así:

```
$array1
$array2
$array3
...
```

Pueden ser 2 array o 10, la cuestión es que necesito combinar los array que tenga ciertos parámetros iguales, iterar sobre ellos para después armar un array único con los valores tratados. Intente con producto cartesiano pero el problema es que son mas de 2 y no entendí como aplicarlo a mas de 2...

Entiendo que si hago esto me funciona y puedo trabajarlo de manera estática:

```
foreach($array1 as $value1){
    foreach($array2 as $value2){
        foreach($array3 as $value3){
            if($value1['valor1] == $value2['valor1] ){
                if($value1['valor1] == $value3['valor1]){
                    if($value1['valor1] == $value3['valor1]){
                    $arrayNuevo = []; //Creo un nuevo array combinando algunos valores del contenido

                    }
                }
            }

        }     
    }
}
```

El problema es que los array son dinámicos, como podría comparar y combinar varios arrays de manera dinámica?
Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan prestar.

Comment: ¿Puedes proponer un ejemplo concreto? ¿De qué arrays partes y qué te gustaría conseguir?

Comment: Bueno el ejemplo mas concreto es un poco mas complicado, porque obtengo ese conjunto de array de un XML, accedo a los conjuntos de array desde un nodo padre y recorro esos nodos, necesito compararlos y combinarlos... por eso trate de hacer el ejemplo general para ver si logro trasmitir la idea que realmente quiero.

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo? la realidad es que no entiendo la fuente de los array vienen de un sql o de que? y que resultado final esperas?.

Comment: coloque la idea general en un comentario anterior, el ejemplo es un poco complicado plantearlo aqui...

Comment: Voy a editar para ver...

Comment: agregue información.

Comment: No es necesario que pongas el ejemplo real, sino unos datos de ejemplo, para que entendamos qué quieres hacer: de qué partimos y a qué queremos llegar

Comment: podrias agregar un ejemplo de lo que contienen minimo 2 arreglos? para saber que data deseas compara o combinar en 1.

Comment: la cuestion es que es un XML y accedo a los datos por Foreach, son objetos que arroja la lectura de un xml, por eso es un poco complicado plantearles la realidad. Por eso lo hice colocandolo solo con array